# Multiple parents in typeorm tree structure?

Tags: typeorm, tree-structure

I have an application that uses Materialized Path to map a folder structure. Now I want to change it so that it is possible to link folders logically in multiple places (so a folder can have multiple parents). Is this possible with TypeORM? I've read a lot in the documentation and found nothing suitable.

Comment: I need to solve a similar problem: I have not a Tree structure, but a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG), every node can have more than a single parent. Is there any support for DAGs with TypeORM ?